# Calculate new value in Delete Rule Action base on current PK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has a PK and has a lot of relationships with other tables based on its PK.

I want to Delete Some rows of the table, and I want to update all FKs of child tables which are associated to these rows with other PK based on the current value of the deleting row PK (with a calculation or IF Statements).

I think the safest way is to declare an delete rule action in the parent table for all children relations. but SQL Server Delete rule action just contain [Set to NULL, Set Default, No Action, Cascade Delete]

Is there any way to execute a function in Delete Rule Action and Calculate New value for set in children FKs? and if not, please recommend me a safe solution for this problem.

thank you

Comment: if you need a custom logic in place, can't you use triggers ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Yes, you're right. It seems there is no better way. and it seems we can not execute any custom logic in delete rule action. Thank you